# Expanding records in Power BI from oData feed for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I'm receiving an error when expanding columns containing records for a filtered odata query for the WorkItems Table. There are multiple columns I would like to expand, but I'll show Area as an example (To access AreaPath data)

First Query Code

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/My_Org/My_Project/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?"
    &"$filter=WorkItemType eq 'Product Backlog Item'"
    &"&$select=WorkItemId, WorkItemType, Area"
    ,null, [Implementation="2.0"])
in
    Source
```

Error Code

```
DataSource.Error: OData: Request failed: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (VS403483: The query specified in the URI is not valid: VS403489: The Analytics Service doesn't support key or property navigation like WorkItems(Id) or WorkItem(Id)/AssignedTo. If you getting that error in PowerBI, please, rewrite your query to avoid incorrect folding that causes N+1 problem..)
Details:
    DataSourceKind=OData
    DataSourcePath=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/My_Org/My_Project/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems(1877327)/Area
    Url=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/My_Org/My_Project/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems(1877327)/Area
```

[image: Error Message]

[image: Results for filtered data]

I do not receive this error when accessing the data without filtering. I filter within the Power Query Editor after the data is imported.

Second Query Code

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/My_Org/My_Project/_odata/v4.0-preview", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    WorkItems_table = Source{[Name="WorkItems",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(WorkItems_table,{"WorkItemId", "WorkItemType", "Area"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each ([WorkItemType] = "Product Backlog Item")),
    #"Expanded Area" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Area", {"AreaPath"}, {"Area.AreaPath"})
in
    #"Expanded Area"
```

[image: Results for un-filtered data]

Why can't the record be expanded when the query is written as the first, but can on the second?  Is there a way to make it happen?

How can I push the filter to occur at the source with the second query?

I need to be able to filter the data at the source as it pulls in hundreds of thousands of rows if not.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what is causing the error. But I've decided to pull in the corresponding tables and create relationships with the filtered WorkItems table. Every field that I want to expand has a unique surrogate key that I can use to connect to the reference tables and pull in the necessary information.